# What is the variance of a variable that can either be 0 or or a constant depending on a Gaussian distributed variable?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, bernoulli-distribution

I need to determine the variance of a variable b(v). The variable is defined as the following:

$$
b(v) = \begin{cases}
\beta, \quad \text{if } v<0,\\
0, \quad \text{if } v\geq0.\\
\end{cases}
$$

As you can see, it is dependent on the random variable $v$. The variable $v$ follows a Gaussian distribution of which I know the mean and the variance. I am however not sure on how to determine the variance of the variable $b$.. Is it similar to the variance of $v$?

Comment: You could start by finding $P(v<0)$.  It is then an easy calculation as a scaled Bernoulli random variable

Comment: Notice, too, that since $\beta$ is a scale factor (it defines the units of measurement in which $b(v)$ is expressed), the variance will be proportional to its square.  Since $\beta$ is logically independent of $v,$ we can expect that the answer will not be "similar to" the variance of $v,$ but that the variance *divided by $\beta^2$* will be determined by $v,$ as @Henry has kindly indicated. If nothing else, this observation shows you may freely set $\beta=1$ without any loss of generality (assuming you're uninterested in the degenerate case $\beta=0$).

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the input. Right now I applied the following reasoning:
b(v) is equal to $\beta$ if $v$ is smaller than $\underline{v}$ and 0 otherwise. I calculated the expectation of $\mathbb{E}(b(v)^2)$ as the following:
$
\mathbb{E}(b(v)_i^2) = \mathbb{P}(b(v)_i=\beta)\beta^2+\mathbb{P}(b(v)_i=0)0^2 = (\mathbb{P}_{v<\underline{v}})\beta^2
$

$
var(b(v)_i) = \mathbb{E}(b(v)_i^2)-\mathbb{E}(b(v)_i)^2 = (\mathbb{P}_{v_i<\underline{v}})\beta^2 - (\beta\mathbb{P}_{v_i<\underline{v}})^2 = (\mathbb{P}_{v_i<\underline{v}})\beta^2 - \beta^2(\mathbb{P}_{v_i<\underline{v}})^2.
$

Comment: Do you think that this reasoning is correct? I am doubting the first equation where I adopt the reasoning from the Bernoulli distribution @whuber

Comment: That's the right answer and the manipulations look correct, too.

Comment: Thank you :) @whuber